# How to use to_widget() to keep some things stationary in a ScatterPlane

Tags: python, kivy

If I want to keep certain elements within a `ScatterPlane` stationary relative to the window, in the kv, I can do:

```
ScatterPlane:
    Label:
        text: 'Locked to Window'
        pos: -root.x, -root.y
```

However, if I try:

```
pos: root.to_widget(0, 0)
```

It doesn't work. Why is this?

Here's some code that demonstrates this:

```
import kivy
kivy.require('1.9.0') 
from kivy.app import App 
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.uix.scatter import ScatterPlane 
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout 
from kivy.lang import Builder 

presentation = Builder.load_string(""" 
<ScatterPlane>: 
    Label: 
        #pos: root.to_widget(0, 0) #doesnt work 
        pos: -root.x, -root.y      #works 
        width: root.width 
        text: 'Test: ' + str(root.pos) + ', ' + str(root.to_widget(0, 0))  

RelativeLayout: 
    ScatterPlane: 
""") 


class TestApp(App): 
    def build(self): 
        return presentation  

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Why not just not put the Label in the ScatterPlane? That would probably be a much easier solution.

Comment: Do you mean put `Label` outside of `ScatterPlane`? That would work, but I put it in the `ScatterPlane` because most of the time, items will move with the scatter, but there will be occasions when the user will want to lock their position to window while the rest of the `ScatterPlane` moves. In that situation, I want it to move opposite to scatter so that the effect is it stays fixed with respect to the window.